# C# send hex string as hex

Tags: c#, character-encoding, hex

I have a string and I want to send it as hex value and not ascii value

my string is :

> 0x5C 0x21 0x5C

but when I send it I send :

> 30-78-35-43-20-30-78-32-31-20-30-78-35-43

how can I over came this?

what am I missing?

this is the full code :

```
         byte[] address = { 0x30, 0x35 };
          byte[] end = { 0x03 };

        string Start = "0x5C 0x21 0x5C 0x73 0x20 0x73";
        for (int x = 0; x < msg.Count; x++)

        Console.WriteLine(Start);



        byte[] ByteMessage = encoding.GetBytes(Start);

        string HexMessage = BitConverter.ToString(ByteMessage);

        var temp = new MemoryStream();
        temp.Write(address, 0, address.Length);
        temp.Write(ByteMessage, 0, ByteMessage.Length);
        temp.Write(end, 0, end.Length);

        byte[] testing = temp.ToArray();
        var lrs = gen(testing);
        string lrsString = lrs.ToString("X");



        Console.WriteLine("MSG in HEX -  " + HexMessage);

        Console.Write(
                      Encoding.Default.GetString(address) +

                      encoding.GetString(ByteMessage) +

                      Encoding.Default.GetString(end) +

                      );



        byte[] LRS = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(lrsString);

        try
        {

            sp1.Write(start, 0, start.Length); //send start 
            sp1.Write(testing, 0, testing.Length);//send the all msg 
            sp1.Write(LRS, 0, LRS.Length);//send the Check Sum 
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);

        }

        finally
        {

        }
```

Thanks ,

Comment: You encoded your hex-string to hex again.

Comment: how do you get `string Start = "0x5C 0x21 0x5C";` in the first place ?

Comment: I need to do it so I can send it using byte[] , no? look at my post - I have added more , Thanks,

Comment: why don't you use `byte[] ByteMessage = new byte[] {0x5C, 0x21, 0x5C, 0x73, 0x20, 0x73};` in the first place ?

Comment: this is example of the string I need to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You, probably, are looking for *parsing* (each `string` item like `"0x5C"` should be parsed into corresponding `byte`: `0x5C`):

```
string Start = "0x5C 0x21 0x5C";

byte[] ByteMessage = Start
  .Split(' ')                               // Split string into items
  .Select(item => Convert.ToByte(item, 16)) // Parse items into corresponding bytes
  .ToArray();                               // Materialize into array

// Back to Hex (let's have a look on what we are going to send): "5C-21-5C"
string HexMessage = string.Join("-", ByteMessage
  .Select(item => item.ToString("X2")));
```

Comment: bye the way - if my string is without "0x" , will it be much simpler? because I have added the "0x" to the string...

Comment: @David12123: `Convert.ToByte(item, 16)` is smart enough to deal with or without `0x` prefix; that's why `string Start = "5C 21 5C";` will be correctly parsed. You don't have to add `"0x"`

Comment: great! , so i will use the string without "0x" = Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

string Start = "\x5C\x21\x5C";
That will put into Start the actual 3 hex codes.  Basically you take the 0's and the spaces out of the string and replace with the backslash.  This is using a C# string escape sequence specifically the \x sequence that will take \x0 to \xFFFF as defined in the documentation here at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/  its about in the middle of the page.

Remember c# strings by default are unicode. if you need a different encoding you need to specify it.